# Kill, Clean, and Restart Firefox

Tags: batch-file, firefox, cmd

This script is supposed to kill Firefox, clean the cache, delete the cookies, reopen Firefox, and run an iMacro.

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /t /im Firefox.exe /im crashreporter.exe >nul 2>&1

set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"

for /d %%x in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite

start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=l4lyt.iim
```

Currently, the first three steps work but Firefox doesn't reopen. Have I forgotten something?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?" Does it do _any_ of the commands in the script? Which part does it break at?

Comment: My script for now Kill firefox, clean cache and cookie but later dont open again firefox... why ?

Comment: You might try waiting a bit after you killed firefox, before you open it again.

Comment: Does `start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=l4lyt.iim` by itself work if you just type it into the command prompt?

Comment: Yes only this working start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=l4lyt.iim

Comment: Sounds like you should try frankenapps' suggestion of a delay before starting firefox back up. Something like `timeout /t 3` should work.